# Truffle vs Hardhat vs Foundry and web3js vs ethersjs

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethers.js, hardhat, foundry

I am relatively new to Web3 and Solidity . When writing smart contracts I usually get struck in which framework to use ... Truffle ( the most I've used so far ) , Hardhat ( just getting started ) and Foundry ( I just know that it exists ) .
Which one is the best according to you ? By best I mean best in terms of community support , minimal problems and easy usage . Main problem that I face is when I am learning through articles / video tutorials , majority of them use Hardhat , some of them use Truffle and the rest use Foundry.
Same is the question I have for using web3js or ethersjs .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it's just foundry. You have the telegram chat for support with the developers of it, it's faster than all the competitors and you can write your own tests/scripts with solidity itself. This means that you don't have to worry about any kind of BigNumber or importing the ABI's for contract interaction.

On the other side, I find that ethersjs is just objectively better than web3js, you can just use RainbowKit, Wagmi or any collection of hooks if you are working with react that will make your life way easier!

Answer (score 3):

Hardhat + ethersjs gave me the best experience in development(web3js gave me anxiety and a wish to die). I have 2 years of experience with these and I could implement complex projects using Hardhat+etherejs. I'm not a fast learner but these ones seem logical when you use them.

I would like to try Foundry because I heard is very nice for testing.